# How to protect files outside of current project in CLion or Other Jetbrains IDEs?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, clion, rubymine

In CLion, it's easy to nevigate to files do not belongs to the current project but is referenced. This is convenient.

But sometimes I might accidently alter them, which I do not want to actually.

How to make all the referenced files readonly in CLion and Other Jetbrain IDEs like Intellig / PyCharm / Rubymine / Android Studio / Webstorm ?

Comment: Usually all JetBrains IDEs ask when you're trying to edit file located outside your project. Could you describe your structure?

Comment: @user2235698  I have a CMake project, which has reference to some other code from different directories.

Comment: If the files are from other projects, configure their source control mappings. Then you will see if they are changed in your SCS view and in a commit dialog.